# HTML5 changing the value of a disabled input shall call a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a HTML5 page in which i got some input controls, which are calling JavaScript-functions for calculations while their oninput-event fires.

Here an example for one of my JS-functions:

```
function txt_DFPG_calculation() {
    var value_KE = ValidateNumberValue(document.getElementById("txt_KE").value.replace(",", "."));
    var value_result_A_B = ValidateNumberValue(document.getElementById("txt_result_A_B").value.replace(",", "."));
    if (value_KE != 0 && value_result_A_B != 0) {
        document.getElementById("txt_DFPG").value = value_KE * value_result_A_B;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("txt_DFPG").value = null;
    }
}
```

And one of the Inputs which calls that function:

```
<input id="txt_KE"
       type="number"
       step="0.01"
       oninput="txt_DFPG_calculation();"
       style="position: absolute; top: 115px; left: 40px; width: 80px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; text-align: right" />
```

Now i have the problem, that only the first input "txt_KE" can be edited.
The value of the second input "txt_result_A_B" results of a calculation from two other inputs and cannot be edited, so it's disabled.
How can the second input call the same function as "txt_KE" even when it's disabled or readonly?

I tried the onchange-event, but this didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: ValidateNumberValue is a JS-function i wrote and which lies in a seperate JS-file.

```
function ValidateNumberValue(value) {
    if (isNaN(value) || value == "") {
        value = 0;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What do You mean with "fiddle"?

Comment: if i understood it correctly then, your input "txt_result_A_B" is a disabled field and you are putting the result of two other input box into it manually, so when you are putting the value after that try to call your function manually

Comment: That's clear. I tried to call the function in the other two inputs from which the value of txt_result_A_B results and this works. But it would be nicer, if i would have a possibility to call the function from the disabled input. Is there no way?

Comment: Unless you want the function to be triggered on any mouse / keyboard event on the disabled textbox, I think i am going to chime in to agree with what @atul has suggested.

Comment: Not on mouse/keyboard Event, but on onchange or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a more [unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup) method - that is, keep JS out of your HTML altogether. Instead, work with the DOM and use the same function(s) wherever you want.

```js
// Create scope (avoids creating global functions/variables)
(function() {
  var
    aEl = document.getElementById('txt_A'),
    bEl = document.getElementById('txt_B'),
    abEl = document.getElementById('txt_result_A_B'),
    keEl = document.getElementById('txt_KE'),
    dfpgEl = document.getElementById('txt_DFPG')
  ;

  function validateNumberValue(value) {
    if (isNaN(value) || value == '') {
      value = 0;
    }
    return value;
  }

  function calculate(firstEl, secondEl, resultEl) {
    var
      value1 = validateNumberValue(firstEl.value.replace(',', '.')),
      value2 = validateNumberValue(secondEl.value.replace(',', '.'))
    ;
    
    if (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0) {
      resultEl.value = value1 * value2;
    } else {
      resultEl.value = null;
    }
  }

  function runCalculations() {
    calculate(aEl, bEl, abEl);
    calculate(keEl, abEl, dfpgEl);
  }

  keEl && keEl.addEventListener('input', runCalculations);
  aEl && aEl.addEventListener('input', runCalculations);
  bEl && bEl.addEventListener('input', runCalculations);
})();
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="number" id="txt_A" placeholder="txt_A" /> *
  <input type="number" id="txt_B" placeholder="txt_B" /> = (txt_result_A_B)
</p>
<p>
  <input type="number" id="txt_KE" step="0.01" placeholder="txt_KE" /> *
  <input type="number" id="txt_result_A_B" placeholder="txt_result_A_B" disabled /> =
  <input type="number" id="txt_DFPG" placeholder="txt_DFPG" disabled />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank You BDawg for Your answer. That's very interesting.